# Is an increase in blood pressure all that you need to increase connective tissue blood flow?

Tags: blood-pressure, blood-circulation, blood-vessels

[An answer](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/a/28702/7951) to the question [Does chronic caffeine use increase or decrease blood flow to connective tissue?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/27692/7951)

Talks only of blood pressure (BP) values when answering the question, which to me is strange, because I am wondering if an increase in BP is all that is needed to increase connective tissue blood flow.

My thinking is that if caffeine causes vasodilation (see https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK202224/)

> Caffeine can also bind directly to the vascular smooth muscle cell receptors and, through similar mechanisms, cause vasodilatation ([Echeverri et al., 2010](https://doi.org/10.1155/2010/834060))

and the heart rate was increased to compensate for lower BP, the blood flow would still be increased, even though the BP was the same.

Or am I misunderstanding something?

### References

Echeverri, D., Montes, F. R., Cabrera, M., Galán, A., & Prieto, A. (2010). Caffeine's vascular mechanisms of action. *International journal of vascular medicine, 2010*. https://doi.org/10.1155/2010/834060